# MySQL - JOIN to identify affect of updates on a single column

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I need to produce a script that can identify how a number of changes affected a certain column of a table. I was unable to explain my problem properly without a good example..

Say we have a database with 5 tables: **employee**, **security_clearance**, **department**, **building** and **building_floor**:

- Each employee has a level of security clearance and a department.
- Each department is associated with a building and a floor.
- Each floor has a required security clearance for working hours and non working hours. Each floor is also associated with a building.

This data is updated regularly, eg. new employees are added, departments may move to a different floor or the security clearance of a whole building may change. Before an update is made, a backup is made of the whole database.

**What I want to achieve, is to detect, for example, which employees are affected if a building floor was added/removed/renamed.**

Let continue with the example.

After a month of several updates, staff started reporting missing equipment; the janitor is missing his broom, the receptionist noticed the staff liquor cabinet was emptied out and accounting lost all its paper clips. It is then concluded by department heads that the company has been plagued by a series of burglaries.

The company CEO, appoints one of the in-house developers to determine how any update to the database, effected each employee, no matter how small the change.

The CEO will expect answers to questions of the following format:

Which employees was affected by the required clearance change for non working hours of the first floor of "Earth House"?

Which employees was affected by the name change of building "Fire House" (previously know as "Wind House")?

The developer has concluded that a massive `LEFT JOIN` is need. He will `JOIN` all the tables related to the **employee** table. If he repeats the `JOIN` on each version, and compare the output, he can determine how each employee was affected by each successive update.

Unfortunately, the developer is unable to produce a `JOIN` that correctly concatenates all the data. Some of the information is not included in that `JOIN` result and quite a bit of it is null. New rows are also not detected.

He also needs answers to the following questions:

- Is a `LEFT JOIN` the right `JOIN` to use in this case?
- How does one successfully `JOIN` tables that have a curricular relation? (department has a **building_floor** and a **building** and **building_floor** also references **building**)
- How does one `JOIN` a table which is referenced twice by the same table? (**building_floor** has **clearance_non_working_hours** and **clearance_working_hours**)
- How extendible will his solution be once a new table is added or a row/column is added/removed?

The tables can be created using the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS security_clearance;
CREATE TABLE security_clearance (
    id INT(5),
    description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS building;
CREATE TABLE building (
    id INT(10),
    name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS building_floor;
CREATE TABLE building_floor (
    id INT(3),
    clearance_working_hours INT NOT NULL,
    clearance_non_working_hours INT NOT NULL,
    building_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(clearance_working_hours) REFERENCES security_clearance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(clearance_non_working_hours) REFERENCES security_clearance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(building_id) REFERENCES building(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) Engine=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS department;
CREATE TABLE department(
    id INT(3),
    name VARCHAR(20),
    building_id INT NOT NULL,
    floor_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(building_id) REFERENCES building(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(floor_id) REFERENCES building_floor(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) Engine=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT(5),
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    position VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    clearance_id INT NOT NULL,
    department INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(clearance_id) REFERENCES security_clearance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

The tables can be populated with the following:

```
INSERT INTO security_clearance VALUES(0, "public - accessible to employees and visitors");
INSERT INTO security_clearance VALUES(1, "private - accessible to employees only");
INSERT INTO security_clearance VALUES(2, "restricted - accessible to officials only");
INSERT INTO security_clearance VALUES(3, "NO ACCESS ALLOWED");

INSERT INTO building VALUES(0, "Water House");
INSERT INTO building VALUES(1, "Fire House");
INSERT INTO building VALUES(2, "Earth House");

insert into building_floor values (0, 0, 1, 0);
insert into building_floor values (1, 1, 2, 0);
insert into building_floor values (2, 0, 0, 1);
insert into building_floor values (3, 1, 1, 2);
insert into building_floor values (4, 2, 3, 2);

INSERT INTO department VALUES(0, "Reception", 0, 0);
INSERT INTO department VALUES(1, "Finance", 0, 1);
INSERT INTO department VALUES(2, "HR", 1, 2);
INSERT INTO department VALUES(3, "Development", 2, 3);
INSERT INTO department VALUES(4, "Storage", 2, 4);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(0, "Jan", "Janitor", 1, 2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1, "Sarah", "Receptionist", 1, 0);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(2, "Bianca", "Receptionist - Assistant", 1, 0);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(3, "John", "Accountant - Junior", 2, 1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(4, "Sandy", "Accountant", 2, 1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(5, "Laura", "Manager", 1, 2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(6, "Ian", "Java Developer - Junior", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(7, "Daniel", "Java Developer - Team Lead", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(8, "Frank", "CEO", 2, 2);
```

Here is the `JOIN` statement that the developer managed to produce thus far:

```
SELECT employee.id,
       employee.name,
       employee.position,
       security_clearance.id,
       security_clearance.description,
       department.id,
       department.name,
       building.id,
       building.name,
       building_floor.id,
       building_floor.clearance_working_hours,
       building_floor.clearance_non_working_hours
FROM   employee
       LEFT JOIN department on employee.department = department.id
       LEFT JOIN building_floor on department.id = building_floor.id
       LEFT JOIN building on building_floor.building_id = building.id
       LEFT JOIN security_clearance on employee.clearance_id = security_clearance.id
                 AND building_floor.clearance_working_hours = security_clearance.id
                 AND building_floor.clearance_non_working_hours = security_clearance.id;
```

The output of the `JOIN`:

```
id  name    position    id  description id  name    id  name    id  clearance_working_hours clearance_non_working_hours
0   Jan Janitor NULL    NULL    2   HR  1   Fire House  2   0   0
1   Sarah   Receptionist    NULL    NULL    0   Reception   0   Water House 0   0   1
2   Bianca  Receptionist - Assistant    NULL    NULL    0   Reception   0   Water House 0   0   1
3   John    Accountant - Junior NULL    NULL    1   Finance 0   Water House 1   1   2
4   Sandy   Accountant  NULL    NULL    1   Finance 0   Water House 1   1   2
5   Laura   Manager NULL    NULL    2   HR  1   Fire House  2   0   0
6   Ian Java Developer - Junior NULL    NULL    1   Finance 0   Water House 1   1   2
7   Daniel  Java Developer - Team Lead  NULL    NULL    1   Finance 0   Water House 1   1   2
8   Frank   CEO NULL    NULL    2   HR  1   Fire House  2   0   0
```

Note:

This story, which is completely fabricated, exists only to capitulate my problem, which is to produce a `JOIN` that can be used to identify how a set of changes to a database affected a certain column.

I realise that this is a massive question, but the example I have given is a runnable, scaled down version of my actual problem.

Comment: Are  you asking about changes in data or changes in schema?

Comment: @Caleth Main question is only for changes in data. But I also want to know, if this is a viable solution, how viable will it be if schema or table structure changes.